# Failed to instantiate module when using ES6 let with firefox and angular

Tags: angularjs, firefox, ecmascript-6

I try to use the ES6's let keyword in my Angularjs module. I work with AngularJS 1.3 and FF 34. In Chrome ( 39 ) it works . In FF i  get a "Failed to instantiate module". When I change this statement with the var keyword it's all good in FF.

Someone have an idea ?

Comment: can you post some code?

Comment: it's a large project so it's difficult to post just a piece of code but i don't think it's related, I tried in an other location by just adding let test = "test"  and it crash in FF the same way ( ok for chrome )

Comment: I just tried with the angular-seed project. Same effect..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use ES6 features in firefox you need to specify the version

```
<script type="application/javascript;version=1.7"></script>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.7